# Eclipse GMF/GEF different Figures

Tags: eclipse, emf

I using GEF/GMF and now I tried Eugenia.
I want to create a special model, with special forms.
In an example there are some figures called "ellipse", "rectangle" and "rounded".
These are the only figures I know, I can´t find any list with all the different figures to use.
Do someone knows more figures or a website where I can find a list?

Regards
Dotana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution by myself.
For everyone:
The figures are listed under "org.eclipse.draw2d.geometry".